# How can I express this nginx config as apache2 rewrite rules?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite

```
   if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite /iOS/(.*jpg)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /iOS/(.*jpeg)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /iOS/(.*png)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /iOS/(.*css)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /iOS/(.*js)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /Android/(.*jpg)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /Android/(.*jpeg)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /Android/(.*png)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /Android/(.*css)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite /Android/(.*js)$ /$1 last;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /?route=$1 last;
    }
```

There are some vanity URLs e.g. mysite.com/yourdetails which are handled internally by a router class (its a PHP app with index.php as the entry point) and they seem to work fine on nginx but not Apache :-/

I tried this but the vanity URLs are not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

I'd like to rule out Apache config first before I get too deep into the code.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out they were working fine in all browsers other than Chrome Canary which was sending a user agent which the App wasn't recognising (it's a mobile app and the user agent extension for chrome was doing something funky.)